# The name of the object reference

Tags: java, object, reference

Is there a way to get one of the references the object is pointed by?

Eg.: i have the object

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
```

somewhere in the code, i'll be printing the name of that object, which in this case is "obj" -- the only reference to it. In case of multiple references to the object, just to bring me one of them arbitrarily.

Note: i'm aware of

```
obj.getClass().getName()
```

but this-- the type name isn't what i want.

Thanks in advance.

//=====================

**ADD:** JVM clearly knows which references are referring to which objects at a given time. the Q here is whether it tells.

Comment: An object doesn't have a name. Neither do the references. What has a name is a field, a method parameter, or a local variable. You can get the names of fields and, some times, method parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to print out the name of your reference? I don't think this is possible in Java.

Comment: You could get a list of all the field names in a Class, but that would give you all fields Objects... of course, if there is **ONE AND ONLY ONE** then...

Comment: Tell us why you want to do it.  Reasons why it is not achievable have been given by others, but if you tell us why you want to do it, we may suggest a proper way to you

Comment: @AdrianShum: exactly. This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Adrian Shum may wanna know who else is referring where to the object i'm currently processing on. can't think of a specific use in practice. thx for the useful comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are trying to do is not possible, and even if it were possible is not desirable. So my answer to your question is "NO".

**Edit**
For instance, what is the variable name of an object whose only reference is that it is the 3rd item in an array? What is the variable name of a JPanel created anonymously and placed in a GUI (so that it doesn't even have a specific variable that refers to it)? So many objects don't have "names" as you are referring to, and so in many cases what you desire wouldn't even make sense.

Your question sounds like an almost classic example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), like you're barking up the wrong tree, and leading us up the tree with you. Instead of asking how to solve a bad plan, you should give us a complete description of the actual problem you're trying to solve, and not the code plan for how you're currently (and wrongly) trying to solve it.

Comment: Please go into more detail about why it's not desirable, and even useless to have.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: no problem. Your comment was an honest one, and I don't mind the down-vote, whoever gave it. The subject is touchy, and I'm not very subtle in my opinions.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels dont know where youve been "barking at" so far, but some "philosophy" accumulated there clearly. dont get too carried away by Sotiriosdelimenalos. he's always that.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels sry for the delayed response btw. been busy.

Comment: @Roam: you have yet to address the why want this issue that we've requested of you, and so until you do, we probably can't help you.

Comment: To the down-voter: I don't mind the down-vote, but if you think my answer is wrong, then yes, please down-vote me, but also post what you think the right answer is!